# CouchCMS with the repeat tag

Tags: php

I have a code in CouchCMS to repeat generate a repetitive

`<cms:folders masterpage='business.php' folder=k_folder_name>
    <div class="big">
        <cms:repeat count='2'>
            <div class="small">
                <a href="<cms:show k_folder_link />">
                    <img src="<cms:show k_folder_image />" />
                    <cms:show k_folder_name />
                </a>
            </div>
        </cms:repeat>
    </div>
</cms:folders>`

The output of the above code is:

`<div class="big">
    <div class="small">
        <a href="http://localhost/cmi/business.php?f=2">
            <img src="" />
            folder2
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        <a href="http://localhost/cmi/business.php?f=2">
            <img src="" />
            folder2
        </a>
    </div>
</div>`

You can see that the name folder2 is being repeated twice. And hence the output that I am getting is that the same folder image and folder name are being outputted.

My aim is to achieve the following code:

`<div class="big">
    <div class="small">
        <a href="http://localhost/cmi/business.php?f=1">
            <img src="" />
            folder1
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        <a href="http://localhost/cmi/business.php?f=2">
            <img src="" />
            folder2
        </a>
    </div>
</div>`

where in folder1 and folder2 are both displayed. What changes will I need to do in the Couch coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cms:folders tag itself will repeat the enclosed contents as many times as there are folders to be listed so no need for the additional cms:repeat tag. Following should produce the code you are looking for

```
<div class="big">
    <cms:folders masterpage='business.php'>
    <div class="small">
        <a href="<cms:show k_folder_link />">
            <img src="<cms:show k_folder_image />" />
            <cms:show k_folder_name />
        </a>
    </div>
    </cms:folders>
</div>
```